# PDO INSERT INTO not working?

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert, sql-insert

so I already tried to fix this and I read a lot of questions here on StackOverflow but non of them helped me. So I have a working MySQL connection with PDO and I can SELECT things and stuff but if I try to INSERT something into the DB it wont work. There is no PDO exception the execution of the prepared SQL Query just wont work.

My Code that doesn't work:

```
$stmt3 = $host->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, passwort, email, key) VALUES (:username, :passwort, :email, :key)");
try{
    if(!$stmt3->execute(array(':username' => $uzernamez, ':passwort' => $password_db, ':email' => $email, ':key' => $key)))
        die("Unknown ERROR!");
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

It just dies with "Unknown ERROR!" so it isn't a PDO exception and yes the connection is working because 4 lines above I query if the user already exists and that works just fine.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word make sure to use ` ` (backticks) to wrap the reserved words.

Comment: Thx I just changed the key to activationkey and now everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> key is a reserved word make sure to use ` ` (backticks) to wrap the reserved words. –  Abhik Chakraborty

Or just rename the key to whatever fits your needs as I did.